# JQuery plugin Lightbox cross bar are not show

Tags: jquery, html, css

when click icon then show image but cross bar not show.how to show that.
i'm using that

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox.css">
<script src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
<a href="images/gallery_image/Gallery_img.png" data-lightbox="roadtrip">
    <i class="fa fa-search-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lightbox.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<section id="examples" class="examples-section">
        <div class="container">

          <h2>Example</h2>
          <h3>Individual images</h3>
          <div class="image-row">
            <a class="example-image-link" href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="example-1"><img class="example-image" src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-1.jpg" alt="Girl looking out people on beach"></a>
</div>
</div>
</section>
<script src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/84sprk46/

Check the above example working fine.

Comment: i want cross bar show and when click cross bar then images show out